# Is this an instar of the red fire bug?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

While inspecting some yarrow that seemed to be having problems, I found a few of these bugs. I *think* they may be an instar of red firebug, but the photos of the nymphs that I found had only one row of black dots (e.g. [here](https://www.extension.uidaho.edu/publishing/html/BUL1019-Red-Firebug-A-New-Idaho-Invader.aspx#Cycle) along the back) whereas these have two, maybe more. (US, midatalntic, tiny!!! Maybe 1.5 mm?)

Are these firebugs or something else? (Sorry for the poor quality photo.)[image]